# iOS: playing sound while other apps are playing

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

in my app i need to play alert sounds.
if another app (like spotify) is running, when i run my code it stops the music from spotify whenever the alert sound plays.
is there anyway to avoid this?

this is my play sound code:

```
- (void)playSendSound
{
    NSString* path;
    NSURL* url;

    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundBit" ofType:@"aif"];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    player = nil;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: How could you find out other apps like spotify is running?

Comment: when i run the app (through xcode or not) and spotify was playing in the background, it stopped the sound coming from spotify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `AVAudioPlayer` to play your alert sound and sure it will stop whatever music that is playing.

Modify your code to the following:

```
NSString* path;
NSURL* url;

path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundBit" ofType:@"aif"];
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = nil;
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error];
[player play];
```

This should prevent the sound that is playing to stop when you play your alert sound.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much! i will test it soon, as my server is down now :(